# Bootstrap - Active class loses its focus while I click on background area

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I have navbar and it have some menus in the anchor tag.

When I click the menu, it remains selected but when I click somewhere in the background then it loses that active class.

How to overcome this, please help

Below is the snippet of same

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you've described is the normal and expected behavior. Not sure why you'd want to change that...

Comment: ya I know But just imagine that you clicked on the first menu and then you scroll down and clicked somewhere in the background then this menu losing its active tab which its wrong.a user might be confused then on which tab they have clicked earlier? @WebDevBooster

Comment: Are you talking about a single-page website i.e. where the navbar is for navigating different sections of the same page?

Comment: I am saying like this menu: https://www.flyingpenguins.in, its highlighting menu once its active and remain active until you dont change the menu. @WebDevBooster

Comment: That is done by adding the class `active` to the list item the user clicks on.

Comment: Exactly I am doing same. But in my case its losing active class on background click.Why so? @WebDevBooster

Comment: Because in your case you aren't actually linking anywhere.

Comment: If you link to an actual page, you need to make sure that the `active` class is added there (on that page) to the appropriate menu item.